# Sound not even on playback

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Why is the sound volume not consistent. some videos on youtube play loud some too quiet. Same thing with pithos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have different recorded at volumes.  The only way I know to fix this is to use something like VLC's volume normalization, which is not desirable for many people in many instances.

Comment: although it would make a killer home product for the hearing impaired and elderly if someone decided to implement a hardware device